# How to disable a function if document contains element

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, keyboard, lightbox

so, I have a website which scrolls from left to right using the arrow keys. I also have a lightbox which also uses arrow keys to navigate through each image. Is there a way for the function to not fire when the lightbox has been appended?

something like this:

```
$('body').keydown( function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
if ($("body").has("#lightbox").length< 0) { do nothing }
else {
    {
    do something
    }
    });
```

to be clear: the element #lightbox will only exist/be appended after the lightbox trigger element has been clicked

Comment: Is there something wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: so call preventDefault

Comment: `length` will never be less than zero

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').keydown( function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
if ($("body").has("#lightbox").length > 0) { do something }
else {
{
do nothing
}
});
```

?